# Okay to use old Google-Play-Services API?

Tags: android, version, google-play-services

My app is currently targeting API level 8 (Android 2.2). After the Google-Play-Services API was updated my app failed building because it (play-services) now requires at least API level 9.

I worked around this issue by specifying

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32"
```

in my build.gradle as this seems to be the newest version of it that has a minSdk set to 8.

I haven't found any changelog for the play-services API but since it updated to a new major version, I think it would most likely contain any bug-fixes or new features.

Are there any negative consequences with leaving Google-Play-Services API on an old version?

Comment: You might want to just consider dropping 2.2 and moving to 2.3.  According to google, less than .7% of all downloads in the play store were 2.2 last month

Comment: Check your SDK Manager, there is a separate **Google Play services for Froyo**. I'm not sure how it works, but seeing as it's there (and being updated) it might be best to use that one.

Comment: Hi. I couldn't get the point. You're basically compiling/retrieving the client library - not the Google Play APK. And you should be able to retreive it without worrying the device support. However, you should always check if Google Play Services is enabled for your particular service(s).